# How can I pass TypeScript interfaces to an Input?

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have the following interface:

```
/** carddetail.ts */
export interface CardDetail {
   name: string;
   type: string;
   logo?: string;
```

How can I make sure `@Input()` decorators accept this type of data?

```
import { CardDetail } from '../card-detail'

@Input cardDetail: CardDetail
export class CardComponent {
}
```

This gives me the error: `'CardDetail' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

Is there some other approach to use ? In my parent class I define a

```
carddetails = CardDetail[]

constructor() {
 this.carddetails = [
      { name: "foo", logoUrl:'/assets/foo.png', type: "bar" } 
      ...
 ]
```

and pass those values in an *ngFor in the template

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let cardDetail of carddetails">
    <app-card [cardDetail]="cardDetail"></app-card>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input` should be inside component class .Also you will need to add `()` after `@Input` so it should be

```
export class CardComponent {
   @Input() cardDetail: CardDetail
}
```

instead of

```
@Input cardDetail: CardDetail
export class CardComponent {
}
```

also from your parent class it seems like you are passing an array if so,then it should become

```
@Input() cardDetail: CardDetail[];
```